# Minecraft Server Ram Error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I made a local minecraft server on my PC with 16GB of DDR3 ram and the newest version of java and my friend could join just fine, but when I try to add more RAM to the server, it won't boot up for some reason. Does anyone know why this would be?

> C:\Users\MikePc\Desktop\MC server>java -Xms1G -Xmx2G -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
>
> C:\Users\MikePc\Desktop\MC server>PAUSE
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Do you actually *have* that much ram in your machine?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you only have 32 bit version of Java installed. If your PC actually has 16GB of RAM, that means you are running a 64-bit Operating System. **Switch to 64 bit java and you can allocate more memory.**

Per [this oracle FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit)

> **Why can't I get a larger heap with the 32-bit JVM?**
>   The maximum theoretical heap limit for the 32-bit JVM is 4G. Due to various additional constraints such as available swap, kernel address space usage, memory fragmentation, and VM overhead, in practice the limit can be much lower. **On most modern 32-bit Windows systems the maximum heap size will range from 1.4G to 1.6G.** On 32-bit Solaris kernels the address space is limited to 2G. On 64-bit operating systems running the 32-bit VM, the max heap size can be higher, approaching 4G on many Solaris systems

Comment: no i have a 64 bit latest version of java mt pc is 64 bit win 10 pro and the hard ware isn't the problem for is anyone is thinking that.

Comment: @DragonGaming can you open a command prompt in windows and type "java -version"